# How to customize the dataGridView cells in visual studio

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

I want to customize the size of dataGridView cell, how can I do that? iwant to increase the height of cell

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample I am using:

```
    .Grid td { //these are data cells
        background-color: #d7e1e5;
        color: black;
        font-size: 10pt;
        line-height: 200% // Adjust the height here
    }

    .Grid th { //Header cells
        background-color: #007FFF;
        color: White;
        font-size: 10pt;
        line-height: 200% // Adjust the height here
    }
```

Comment: How does this apply to a DataGridView column (WinForms)?